Best way to disconnect and re-attach water softener
I have a water softener that is connected to my supply with 1" PEX A.  I need to move the softener about 2', pivoting around a waste line, to allow for a bathroom to be built where the softener currently stands.  Is it possible to disconnect and reconnect the water softener without messing with PEX A expansion tools?  For example, can I somehow remove the softener bypass value then reinstall it while twisting the PEX A couplers and moving the line?  This manual appears to be close to my model.
The star indicates where I want to move the softener to:




Yes it's possible without using the expansion tool. Cut the PEX as needed and use tool-less connectors (eg: shark-bite)  to re-connect as needed.
Maybe you can unbolt that valve from the back of the tank and pass it behind the drain stack but then the PEX is going to be all bent out of shape when you try to reinstall the tank,  maybe you can twist the pex on those elbow fittings and install the tank in front of the hopper.  but I don't think the PEX warranty covers that.

Fair, but since everything so far is uponor - doing that would impact my current warranty.  Appreciate the answer just mentioning it has implications.

yes, now you have the hassle of dealing with two warranty programs, instead of one.
